# How to set up company mode for ESS Julia

Tags: company-mode, ess

I have ESS installed and I do get company mode drop down menus, but there's nothing Julia specific. For example, I get completion options for functions or variables that I have defined elsewhere in the code, but I do not get options for anything in the julia language.

These are the julia/ess related lines in my .emacs:

```
(load "ess-site")
(setq inferior-julia-program-name "/usr/bin/julia")
```